# How do I set a delay between each iteration of an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, settimeout

I have an array that indicates each sounds I want to play (inpData). Will be appended through html input values.
I want to iterate through the list and add a delay between each sound play.
so far i have tried this:

```
var inpData = [];

function iterateArr(){
    var delay = 1000;
    setTimeout(function(){
        for(var i=0; i<inpData.length; i++){
            window['sound'+inpData[i]].play()
        }

        if(inpData.length)
            iterateArr(inpData)
    }, delay);
};
```

**Currently** it only loops the most recent item entered. For example if:

```
var inpData = ['G'];
```

it will infinitely loop G.
and if Enter a new note, F :

```
var inpData = ['G', 'F'];
```

it will infinitely loop F, while G is still looping.

**What I want.. IF:**

```
var inpData = ['G', 'F', 'E'];
```

I want the code to play G, delay 1 second; play F, delay 1 second; play E; stop.

thanks ahead of time for the help!

**PS**
This is for my web dev project. As we have not learned JQuery yet, please do not answer with that. Thank you.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the `if` condition ? further, the timeout should be *inside* the for-loop, no ?

Comment: that was my attempt to stop the loop when array is done iterating

Comment: you have a for loop that ends when the index reached the "end" - why do you have to "stop" it ?

Answer (score 0):

First, you say it's infinite looping - well that's probably cuz you never remove the items out of `inpData[]` and then you always check `inpData.length` which will never change.  If that's unintentional, you can do `inpData.splice(i, 1)` instead of `inpData[i]`.

Anyway, now for the real part.

**I vote `async/await` for this**

(cuz I just watched a video today and this is perfect timing).

First you make a function that returns a promise, like this:

```
const makeTimer = val =>
  new Promise(resolve =>
    setTimeout(() => resolve(val), 1000)
  );
```

This will take your input ('G', '..') and resolve after 1 second.

```
async function iterateArr () {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    const key = await makeTimer('sound' + inpData[i]);

    // or you can do this
    // const key = await makeTimer('sound' + inpData.splice(i, 1));

    // This now happens every 1000ms
    window[ key ].play();
  }
}

iterateArr();
```

This one does the iteration like you do kinda but a little differently.

It doesn't make it out of each iteration until the full 1000ms has passed.

This is however ES2017 (new syntax) but is already supported in Chrome, Firefox and Node 8+.

If nothing else at least have fun with it :) Check out this video on async/await (the one I watched earlier) - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NsQ2QIrQShU